# the instance method not included by mixin

Tags: ruby, inheritance, mixins

I got `add_log method not defined error` When I call `add_log` in the `AlarmLogger`,

But the `AlarmLogger` has already `inherited Logger`

How do I fix it, Thanks

**test.rb**

```
include TestingDataLoad
class AlarmLogger < Logger
   def run()
    add_log do | new_log, response|
      new_log.brief_content = hash_values_to_int(response[:values])
    end
  end
```

**testing_data_load.rb**

```
module TestingDataLoad

  class Logger



     def add_log
end
end
```

Comment: Please show your full code, not just a snippet. We can't diagnose what's wrong from what is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may be inheriting from the standard library Logger class.

You can easily verify this by adding

```
puts Logger.inspect
```

after your include. If it outputs "TestingDataLoad::Logger" then it has picked your class, if not it hasn't.

The easiest fix would be to have `AlarmLogger` inherit from `TestingDataLoad::Logger`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should require the file before you include it

```
require 'testing_data_load'

include TestingDataLoad
class AlarmLogger < Logger
   def run
    add_log do | new_log, response|
      new_log.brief_content = hash_values_to_int(response[:values])
     end
   end
end
```